# Server Side Pagination not working for the first page kendo grid mvc wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

> As my kendo grid take too much time to load if data is more than 15000
>   records, i think of implementing server side paging.
>
> I am not using entity framework. I am using Kendo MVC wrapper and SQL
>   Server Stored procedures to pull and display the data.
>
> I have passed two parameters to Procedure as @Skip and @Take.
>
> Following is my code :
>
> **View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("expandedView_" + Model.ToArray()[0].WidgetId.ToString())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FacilityNameAbbreviation).Title(@Resource.FacilityName).Width("15%");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DeviceAbbreviation).Title(@Resource.DeviceName).Width("10%");
        columns.Bound(p => p.EventType).Title(@Resource.EventType).Width("40%");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SubEventCode).Title(@Resource.SubAlarmCode).Width("10%").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.FacilityEventTime).Title(@Resource.EventTime).Width("15%");
        columns.Bound(p => p.EventStatus).Title(@Resource.Status).Width("10%");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PriorityColor).Hidden(true);
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(dt => dt
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(100)
    .Read(read => read.Action("PageWiseData", "DeviceEvent", new { WidgetId = Model.ToArray()[0].WidgetId, FacilityIds = ViewData["Facids"].ToString() }))
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.FacilityEventTime)))
)
```

> **Actions :**

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(Exception), View = "ApplicationError")]
public PartialViewResult DeviceEventExpandedView(int WidgetId, string FacilityIds)
{
    var userDetail = sessionContext.UserContextBag;

    int Skip = 0; // for first page data static value is passed
    int Take = 100;

    IList<AMI.WebRole.Models.Widgets.DeviceEventModel> result = _deviceEventClient.DeviceEventsForExpandedView(WidgetId, FacilityIds, TenantId, CustomerId, UserId, this.sessionContext.UserContextBag.CultureName, Skip, Take);

    return PartialView(result);
}


public ActionResult PageWiseData(int WidgetId, string FacilityIds, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IList<AMI.WebRole.Models.Widgets.DeviceEventModel> Totalresult = null;

    var Skip = (request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize;
    var Take = request.PageSize;

    Totalresult = _deviceEventClient.DeviceEventsForExpandedView(WidgetId, FacilityIds, TenantId, CustomerId, UserId, this.sessionContext.UserContextBag.CultureName, Skip, Take);

    return Json(new
        {
            Data = Totalresult,
            Total = 1500
        });
}
```

**PROBLEM :**

> For the first time "DeviceEventExpandedView" is called, view is loaded
>   and data is displayed successfully, BUT THE PAGE NUMBER APPEAR AS 1
>   ONLY for the first time. In my grid, filters are also there, once i
>   click on filter the method "PageWiseData" is called again it pull 100
>   records and this time is shows page number for subsequent pages. As
>   per my understanting second time the returned data is in JSON which
>   also includes Total=1500, but in first case when the partial view is
>   loaded, this count "Total" is not set.
>
> **I am not able to show the page numbers (should be upto 15 in my case) when the partial view is loaded and grid is bind for the first
>   time**
>
> CAN ANY ONE HELP HERE, HOW TO PASS COUNT FOR THE FIRST TIME or HOW TO
>   BIND THE GRID WITH METHOD "PageWiseData" FOR THE FIRST TIME....OR any
>   other way to do this...please help !!

Comment: Your `Action` is doing it wrong, let Kendo filter your result as explained by @hutchonoid.

Comment: i think, for this i have to pull all the records from the DB first, am I right??

Comment: No, `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` will apply its own filter and pagination to the query, so only the required records will be retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the following you should not need to care or worry about handling the paging yourself.

- Change your `totalResult` variable to be an `IQueryable<AMI.WebRole.Models.Widgets.DeviceEventModel>` instead
- Change the `DeviceEventsForExpandedView` method, remove `Skip` and `Take` parameters and also make sure it returns an `IQueryable<AMI.WebRole.Models.Widgets.DeviceEventModel>`

If you return `IQueryable` Kendo should apply sorting and filtering at the DB rather than in memory.

Also make sure you use the `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` to return the result as follows:

```
public ActionResult PageWiseData(int WidgetId, string FacilityIds, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<AMI.WebRole.Models.Widgets.DeviceEventModel> totalresult = null;

    var totalresults = _deviceEventClient.DeviceEventsForExpandedView(WidgetId, 
          FacilityIds, TenantId, CustomerId, UserId,
           this.sessionContext.UserContextBag.CultureName);

        var results = totalresults.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(results);

}
```

Good article on the subject:

[**Server Paging, Sorting, and Filtering with Kendo DataSourceRequest**](http://blog.falafel.com/server-paging-sorting-filtering-kendo-datasourcerequest/)

Comment: i think, for this i have to pull all the records from the DB first, am I right??

Comment: @devgal Yes, just make sure it returns an `IQueryable` which is deferred. :)

Comment: but my Stored Procedure takes 42 seconds if i pull all the records, if i pass skip and take to procedure for 100 records it takes 13 seconds....I dont want to pull all the records from DB itself....can it be possible??

Comment: It will not pull all the records. Kendo will apply its filter and pagination to the query and THEN it will pull the **relevant** record.

Comment: @RosdiKasim As per my understanding of above code,  hutchonoid solution is pulling all the records and keeping it in "totalresults" variable. After this we are applying filter  through this code, "totalresults.ToDataSourceResult(request);"

Comment: If you change the return type to `IQueryable` as advised, the query will not  be executed yet. Google 'iqueryable vs ienumerable performance'.

Comment: @hutchonoid do you have any solution?? i have written ServerOperation as true, so why its not hitting the Second Method on page load??

Comment: @hutchonoid Also what i am returning in the Second ActionResult as json, I kept same in ViewBag **ViewBag.CombineData = Json(new { Data = result, Total = 1200 });** , in First ActionResult ...but not able to bind kendo from viewbag on page load in jquery only for the first time..

Comment: @devgal The grid is configured for ajax, I would not advise using the ViewBag.

Comment: @RosdiKasim i googled it, i think you are RIGHT, it supports late execution and bring filtered data from server, not all of them to client side...Let me give it a try...**BUT before that i have a concern, Is the above posted code is automatically called for the first time when the partial view is loaded, if yes HOW??**

Comment: @hutchonoid I need your attention too on : for the very first time how the above code solution will be called just after the partial view is loaded??

Comment: @devgal Kendo will just call the method as you have specified it within your mark-up.

Comment: @hutchonoid So why it not called previously on my previous "NOT WORKING" code, as i have specified it in markup that time also??  Answer to this question will surely expand my knowledge...!!

Comment: @devgal I think maybe because it is not using the expected return type i.e. using `ToDataSourceResult`.